# Nginx map directive not matching rules

Tags: nginx, redirection

I have this nginx config file:

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
    default DEFAULT;
    /shell http://shell.com;
    /lol http://lol.com;
}
map $request_uri $ret_code {
    default 301;
    /shell 301;
    /lol 302;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name TestDomain.com www.TestDomain.com;

    location / {
        add_header X-request_uri $request_uri;
        add_header X-new_uri $new_uri;
        add_header X-return_code $ret_code;
        if ($new_uri = "DEFAULT") {
            return 301 https://ashfame.com$request_uri;
        }
        if ($ret_code = 301) {
            return 301 $new_uri;
        }
        if ($ret_code = 302) {
            return 302 $new_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

The map directive is not working at all, just defaulting to whatever its defined for default.

For example:

```
$ curl -I testdomain.com/lol
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 22 Jan 2017 20:04:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://ashfame.com/lol
X-request_uri: /lol
X-new_uri: DEFAULT
X-return_code: 301
```

`/lol` should have set `$new_uri` as `http://lol.com` and `$ret_code` as `302`, but if you look at the `X-` headers, its just taking the default values specified in the mapping.

A week back I got this same nginx config working, and there hasn't been any change since then. I do have ubuntu's auto security upgrades on, but don't think nginx was even updated. Running `v1.10.0`. Can't really point out why this stopped working.

Edit: Just tested this same config on a different VPS, same nginx version and it works over there correctly. How do I even fix this now?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. I had multiples of such config files for each domain and since map is defined in http context the last one was overwriting the value of variables. I fixed it by suffixing the variable name in each config file, so that variables are unique:

```
map $request_uri $new_uri_5 {
    default DEFAULT;
    /shell http://shell.com;
    /lol http://lol.com;
}
map $request_uri $ret_code_5 {
    default 301;
    /shell 301;
    /lol 302;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name TestDomain.com www.TestDomain.com testdomain.com www.testdomain.com;

    location / {
        add_header X-request_uri $request_uri;
        add_header X-new_uri $new_uri_5;
        add_header X-return_code $ret_code_5;

        if ($new_uri_5 = "DEFAULT") {
            return 301 https://ashfame.com$request_uri;
        }
        if ($ret_code_5 = 301) {
            return 301 $new_uri_5;
        }
        if ($ret_code_5 = 302) {
            return 302 $new_uri_5;
        }
    }
}
```

5 is the ID of this particular domain in my system.

Comment: Wow, many answers on serverfault but no one pointed that the variables need to be unique on each domain configuration file. I've been wondering why mapping works one one configuration file but not working on another website. Now it all make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing the same issue on Nginx 1.12.2 -- map directive would not match any of the patterns, even the simplest and most trivial ones like `/`, and always used the default value.

The issue tuned out to be caused by the use of the `$uri` variable in the mapping. Some Nginx configuration was implicitly modifying the `$uri` from its original value by prepending `/index.php` prefix which caused the pattern mismatch. Such behavior of `$uri` is by design and the exact distinction between [`$request_uri` and `$uri` variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html).

The fix was to replace the URI variable in the Nginx config:

```
map $uri $result_var {
    # ...
}
```

with the following:

```
map $request_uri $result_var {
    # ...
}
```